# When the button is focused?

Tags: java, android, ios

What is the visual difference between `focused`/`pressed` on mobile device (android)?
Other status are interesting too, but those are most popular to distinguish.

Could you provide any graphics?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

**state_focused** is whenever the button is focused on using a dpad or the trackball. Views don't generally show a focused state when using touch.

**`android:state_pressed`**
Boolean. "true" if this item should be used when the object is pressed (such as when a button is touched/clicked); "false" if this item should be used in the default, non-pressed state.

**`android:state_focused`**
Boolean. "true" if this item should be used when the object has input focus (such as when the user selects a text input); "false" if this item should be used in the default, non-focused state.

**Edit :**

For Button :

`android:state_focused` **is whenever the button is focused on using a dpad or the trackball. Views don't generally show a focused state when using touch.**

You Also Should Refer This Link For Detailed Information About [**State List**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)

Answer (score 1):

its something like this

By the way you can check google for something like this it'll be faster for you :)

[image: simply its like this]